# I am trying to migrate a live wordpress website to my local computer using Duplictor plugin but I am having some issues

Tags: wordpress

For the wordpress live website migration to localhost, I am using the Duplicator plugin, everything works fine except at the end when I try to test my website i get this error "The site is experiencing technical difficulties. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.". Can someone tell me how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turninf ON debug in `wp-config.php`
Also if you local environment php version is lower then 5.5 you can have some issues with latest WP version.
If you don't get anything useful when debug is on, then compare live an local php versions `<?php phpinfo() ?>`